# UNC path login information in a SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, unc

I have stored procedure which should read CSV files from a Network Shared Drive in order to do BULK INSERT. I'm specifying the UNC path of Network Shared Drive using the variable @path. As the Network Shared Drive is secured, I need to pass the login information too and I'm not sure how to do that, can someone please help.

Below is what I have done so far

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(4000)
DECLARE @path varchar(2000)
SELECT @path='\\usanfsd01\Data\*.csv'
SELECT @cmd = 'Dir "' + @path + '"'
```

Comment: Can't you run the sqlserver instance with a domain account and grant that account read permision on the share?

Answer (score 0):

You could map the network drive using a domain account that has permission on the network path  then modify your query to pull from the mapped drive.